# InvalidOperationException when using String.compare in foreach loop

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I simply want to compare a list of strings to a certain value. 
Here's my code:

```
foreach (string s in myList)
            {
                int comp = String.Compare(s, line_to_delete);
                if (comp == 0)
                {
                    myList.Remove(s);
                }
            }
```

The thing is that whenever I use 'comp == 1' I get no exception, but I want it to check if the strings are the same..

Comment: FYI, when you encounter an exception that confuses you, surround the bad code with a `try/catch` block and call `ToString()` on the exception.  The result is the full details of the exception, any inner exceptions, and the call stack.  This information will either be your answer, or if you [edit] and add this to your question, will help others decode your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When iterating a loop with `foreach` you cannot modify the collection because it messes up the iterator.  Either use a `for` loop or keep a list of the strings you want to remove and remove them after the end of the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the exception because you are trying to modify the collection

```
myList.Remove(s);
```

You can't modify the list you are iterating in `foreach` loop. 
See [foreach - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx)

> The foreach statement repeats a group of embedded statements for each
>   element in an array or an object collection that implements the
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable or
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of T) interface. The foreach
>   statement is used to iterate through the collection to get the
>   information that you want, but can not be used to add or remove items
>   from the source collection to avoid unpredictable side effects. **If
>   you need to add or remove items from the source collection, use a for
>   loop.**

For your question:

> the thing is that whenever I use 'comp == 1' I get no exception

Because then it doesn't pass the check and the list remains intact.

I don't know why you are using `string.Compare`, because it seems you are checking for equality.

You can simply do:

```
myList = myList.Where(r=> r != line_to_delete).ToList();
```

If you are trying to use `string.Compare` so that you can perform a case insensitive comparison, then look for [string.Equals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9.aspx) overload which takes `StringComparison` enum for case insensitive comparison as well.

```
myList = myList
            .Where(r => r.Equals(line_to_delete, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `for` loop instead:

```
for (Int32 i = myList.Count - 1; i >= 0 i--)
{
    String s = myList[i];
    if (s.Equals(lineToDelete))
        myList.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

You can't alter the collection while iterating over it.  Looping it in reverse ensures that you don't invalidate the index as you go along removing things (in case you remove more than one matching entry).

Another option:

```
myList.RemoveAll(str => str.Equals(lineToDelete));
```

Comment: `RemoveAll` isn't LINQ, although it is a good method to use to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you're getting the exception because you're trying to modify a collection during an iteration.

You'll be better off doing this:

```
//Remove single instance
var s = myList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Equals(line_to_delete));
if (s != null)
    myList.Remove(s);
```

OR

```
//Remove all instances 
myList = myList.Where(x => !x.Equals(line_to_delete)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify an element of the collection you are enumerating over, to protect the integrity of the enumeration.

You can use a for loop instead. Be sure that you update your index when you remove an element, otherwise you will be operating on the wrong one, and eventually wind up with an index out of bound exception.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myList.Length; i++)
{
    int comp = string.Compare(myList[i], line_to_delete);
    if (comp == 0)
    {
        myList.Remove(i);
        i--;
    }
}
```